# Installing PowerShell Module that supports PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell module that will be installed across a number of servers. The module itself utilizes PowerShell 2.0 features but needs to be able to be imported in both PowerShell 2.0 environments and PowerShell 3.0 environments.

I would like to install a single module into the PSModulePath that can support PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0. As it stands, the 2.0 module manifest looks like this:

```
@{
    ModuleToProcess = "Foo.psm1" # Specific to PowerShell 2.0
    ModuleVersion = "1.0"
    GUID = "8C0AB478-81F7-4B54-B440-521201EAEC1C"
    PowerShellVersion = "2.0"
    FunctionsToExport = "*"
    CmdletsToExport = "*"
    AliasesToExport = "*"
    VariablesToExport = "*"
}
```

Unfortunately, in 3.0 they removed `ModuleToProcess` and replaced it with `RootModule`:

```
@{
    RootModule = "Foo.psm1" # Specific to PowerShell 3.0
    ModuleVersion = "1.0"
    GUID = "8C0AB478-81F7-4B54-B440-521201EAEC1C"
    PowerShellVersion = "2.0"
    FunctionsToExport = "*"
    CmdletsToExport = "*"
    AliasesToExport = "*"
    VariablesToExport = "*"
}
```

My modules are currently deployed so they look something like:

```
C:\FooModules
  Foo-v1.0
    Foo
      Foo.psm1
      Foo.psd1
  Foo-v1.3
    Foo
      Foo.psm1
      Foo.psd1
```

And my PSModulePath is configured such that it contains `C:\FooModules\Foo-v1.0` and `C:\Foomodules\Foo-v1.3`.

This works perfect if I target only 2.0 or only 3.0. But it is the case that I need to support both simultaneously. Is there any way to do this, short of writing a whole mess of preprocessing to install a 2.0 or 3.0 specific manifest? I really would not like to have to do such a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no required change between a v2 manifest and a v3 manifest as far as I know. Use the v2 manifest to keep backwards-compatibility.

`ModuleToProcess` works just fine in v3.

> Note: In Windows PowerShell 2.0, this key was called
>   "ModuleToProcess." You can use the "RootModule" parameter name  or its
>   "ModuleToProcess" alias.

Source: `Get-Help New-ModuleManifest -Parameter RootModule`